# Python Adding Binary Numbers Using "Elementary School" Algorithm

Tags: python, recursion, binary, addition

I have to write a code that takes two input binary numbers (as strings) and add them using the "elementary school" algorithm. This is what the code input and output should look like:

```
>>>addBinary("11","1")
'100'
```

I have tried writing some code myself but I am stuck:

```
def addBinary(s,t, b = 0):
    if '' == s or '' == t:
        return s + t
    if 1 == len(s) or 1 == len(s):    
        if 0 == b:
            if (0 == s[-1] and 1 == t[-1]) or (1 == s[-1]and 0 == t[-1]):
                return addBinary(s[:-1],t[:-1]) + '1'
            elif 0 == s[-1] and 0 == t[-1]:
                return addBinary(s[:-1],t[:-1]) + '0'
            else:
                return addBinary(s[:-1],t[:-1],1) + '0'
        else:
            if (0 == s[-1] and 1 == t[-1]) or (1 == s[-1]and 0 == t[-1]):
                return addBinary(s[:-1],t[:-1],1) + '0'
            elif 0 == s[-1] and 0 == t[-1]:
                return addBinary(s[:-1],t[:-1]) + '1'
            else:
                return addBinary(s[:-1],t[:-1],1) + '0'
```

I am having trouble for when I get down to 1 element left in the string. I am having trouble creating my base case

PS: I have to use recursion for this code. I am not allowed to use loops.

Comment: can you please format the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- Only return `s + t` when `b = 0`, otherwise the returned value will be incorrect.
- No special case is needed for when one of the strings has one digit.
- It is necessary, however, to deal with the case where one of the strings is empty and you could not exit with `s + t` according to the first rule.
- Several repetitions of almost the same code could be avoided

There are several ways to do it, but here is one:

```
def addBinary(s, t, carry = 0):
    if ('' == s or '' == t) and carry == 0:
        return s + t
    digit = carry
    carry = 0
    if s != '' and s[-1] == '1':
        carry = digit
        digit = 1 - digit
    if t != '' and t[-1] == '1': 
        carry += digit
        digit = 1 - digit
    return addBinary(s[:-1], t[:-1], carry) + str(digit)
```

Note that `digit = 1 - digit` is just a way to flip a 1 to 0 and a 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_binary(A:str,B:str)->str:
    result=[]
    carry=0
    i,j=len(A)-1,len(B)-1 # find the max index of strings
    while i>0 or j>0 or carry:
        total=carry # total is initially "carry" then we add values
        if i>=0:
            total+=int(A[i]) # convert the str to int, then add to "total"
            i-=1
        if j>=0:
            total+=int(B[j]) # same as above total operation
            j-=1
        result.append(str(total%2)) # if total=2, we write 0, if total=1, it is 1, if 0 it is 0
        carry=total//2 # if total=2 carry=1, otherwise carry=0
    # so far this is the first iteration
    return ''.join(reversed(result))
```

we did this `reversed(result)` because "010101010", we start the summation from the end, and push it to the array. so last element of binary digits are summed and pushed as the first element of the array. That is why we reversed it.

Answer (score -2):

As a side note, the very last two lines should be:

```py
    else:
        return addBinary(s[:-1],t[:-1],1) + '1'
```

You shouldn't do anything differently when a length is 1. You should do something different when one of the lengths is zero, and you need to properly handle a carry in that case. `return s + t` is incorrect when `b` is `1`.